# How can I have two different Gradle versions in a multi-project project?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, minecraft

I am currently attempting to determine the feasibility of making a particular kind of Minecraft mod using the Forge modding framework. One of the peculiarities of this framework is that it requires a custom Gradle plugin to build the mods (for various copyright-related reasons, given that Minecraft is not FOSS), but this Gradle plugin only works with ancient versions of Gradle. Furthermore, I want to be able to target multiple Minecraft versions in the same code base (essentially, keeping as much common code as possible in shared java library projects), but that requires that I have two sub-projects with different versions of ForgeGradle (Forge's Gradle plugin), and of course those versions require different Gradle versions. I also prefer to use the newest Gradle for the non-Forge parts of this project, which is, of course, incompatible with ForgeGradle. As such, I ask, how can I have different versions of Gradle for different sub-projects in a multi-project Gradle project? If this isn't possible, how can I automate the connection between these projects in an IDE-friendly and single-git-repository-friendly way (mainly IntelliJ Idea Community Edition)? I intend for the versions of the repository to be tracked as a single unit, hence the need for them to be in the same git repo.

Comment: *`Furthermore, I want to be able to target multiple Minecraft versions in the same code base`* You won't be able to accomplish this. Hands down, flat out, zero chance. Too many things get renamed between major Minecraft version releases. Heck, one rename was `Blocks.GRASS` to `Blocks.GRASS_BLOCK` and `Blocks.TALL_GRASS` to `Blocks.GRASS`. Good luck dealing with *that.* Then there's the issue that the `Blocks` class has had its package changed at least once. `BlockXyz` classes also got changed to `XyzBlock`. Etc. etc. etc.

Comment: The heart of your problem is that their plugin is broken. Hence, your only way forward is to create separate projects in neighboring folders, and add some scripts to tie them together, outside of Gradle.

Comment: @Draco18s I'm aware of that. Most of the code in this project doesn't need to link to Forge's classes, so that code can be shared with a relatively thin layer connecting it to a particular Forge version.

Comment: If your code relies on Minecraft's classes, then you're subject to the MCP mapping differences. Which...goes back to what I said earlier. All those renames are because of the MCP mappings. The *Forge* classes are going to be more stable in this regard than the *vanilla* classes.

Comment: @Draco18s in my previous comment, "Forge's classes" is meant to mean "all classes that ForgeGradle makes available, including decompiled and deobfuscated Minecraft classes."

Comment: I...have no idea what you can accomplish without using *any* (or very few) of the Minecraft and Forge classes.

Comment: @barfuin I'm not sure how "we moved to a new version of Gradle" qualifies as "broken." Forge also explicitly no longer supports Minecraft versions older than about 2 years, so Lex doesn't really care. Feel free to tell him he's wrong though (I guarantee that it won't go well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle does not support multiple Gradle versions in the same multi project build. This is also not supported in composite builds.

Given the constraints, the easiest solution would be to work with a local repository to which you publish and from which you fetch your cross project dependencies.